# Open and closed sets in topology

Tags: general-topology

I recently came across the following example which was really surprising:

Let $X= [1,2] \cup [3,4]$? Here $[1,2]$ is both open and closed and same holds fo $[3,4]$. But how is it possible to determine whether the given subset is open or closed just from the above given $X$. Don't we need more information?

Comment: The only additional information needed is that $X$ is being given the topology that it inherits as a subspace of $\Bbb R$ with the usual Euclidean topology.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Under that condition, wouldn't $ [1,2]$ be closed? I am a little confused

Comment: It’s both: it’s open because it’s the intersection with $X$ of the open set $\left(0,\frac52\right)$ in $\Bbb R$, and it’s closed because its complement is open in $X$, being $X\cap\left(\frac52,5\right)$, for instance.

Comment: The unfortunate part about that choice of terminology: unlike a door, a set can be open, closed, both, or neither.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I see. For the first part, you have used the fact that finite intersection of open set is open and similar reasoning for its complement to be open. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: No, I’m just using the definition of subspace topology. If $Y$ is a topological space, and $X$ is a subset of $Y$, a set $U\subseteq X$ is open in the subspace topology on $X$ if and only if there is some open set $V$ in $Y$ such that $U=V\cap X$. (Note that there may be many such sets $V$.)

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $X$, in order to say whether $A \subseteq X$ is open, closed, both, or neither we need to know the topology on $X$. For your example, $X = [1, 2]\cup[3,4]$. You haven't specified the topology, but given your comments, it seems you are considering the subspace topology on $X$.

Given a topological space $(Z, \tau_Z)$, and $Y \subseteq Z$, the subspace topology on $Y$ is $\tau_Y = \{U\cap Y \mid U \in \tau_Z\}$. In your situation, $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which we usually regard as having the topology induced by the metric $d(x, y) = |x-y|$. As Brian has already pointed out in the comments, with this topology, $[1,2]$ and $[3,4]$ are both open and closed.

*Note:* We could obtain the same topology on $X$ by using the induced metric.